# Entity Framework many-to-many question

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

Please help an EF n00b design his database.
I have several companies that produce several products, so there's a many-to-many relationship between companies and products. I have an intermediate table, Company_Product, that relates them.

Each company/product combination has a unique SKU. For example Acme widgets have SKU 123, but Omega widgets have SKU 456. I added the SKU as a field in the Company_Product intermediate table.

EF generated a model with a 1:* relationship between the company and Company_Product tables, and a 1:* relationship between the product and Company_Product tables. I really want a *:* relationship between company and product. But, most importantly, there's no way to access the SKU directly from the model.

Do I need to put the SKU in its own table and write a join, or is there a better way?

Comment: Everything looks fine... You should have 3 entities in your model: Company, Product, and Company_Product.

"there's no way to access the SKU directly from the model" have you tried ctx.Company_Products.First().SKU?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I just tested this in a new VS2010 project (EFv4) to be sure, and here's what I found:

When your associative table in the middle (Company_Product) has ONLY the 2 foreign keys to the other tables (CompanyID and ProductID), then adding all 3 tables to the designer ends up modeling the many to many relationship.  It doesn't even generate a class for the Company_Product table.  Each Company has a Products collection, and each Product has a Companies collection.

However, if your associative table (Company_Product) has other fields (such as SKU, it's own Primary Key, or other descriptive fields like dates, descriptions, etc), then the EF modeler will create a separate class, and it does what you've already seen.

Having the class in the middle with 1:* relationships out to Company and Product is not a bad thing, and you can still get the data you want with some easy queries.

```
// Get all products for Company with ID = 1
var q =
    from compProd in context.Company_Product
    where compProd.CompanyID == 1
    select compProd.Product;
```

True, it's not as easy to just navigate the relationships of the model, when you already have your entity objects loaded, for instance, but that's what a data layer is for.  Encapsulate the queries that get the data you want.  If you really want to get rid of that middle Company_Product class, and have the many-to-many directly represented in the class model, then you'll have to strip down the Company_Product table to contain only the 2 foreign keys, and get rid of the SKU.

Actually, I shouldn't say you HAVE to do that...you might be able to do some edits in the designer and set it up this way anyway.  I'll give it a try and report back.

**UPDATE**

Keeping the SKU in the Company_Product table (meaning my EF model had 3 classes, not 2; it created the Company_Payload class, with a 1:* to the other 2 tables), I tried to add an association directly between Company and Product.  The steps I followed were:

- Right click on the Company class in the designer
- Add > Association
- Set "End" on the left to be Company (it should be already)
- Set "End" on the right to Product
- Change both multiplicities to "* (Many)"
- The navigation properties should be named "Products" and "Companies"
- Hit OK.
- Right Click on the association in the model > click "Table Mapping"
- Under "Add a table or view" select "Company_Product"
- Map Company -> ID (on left) to CompanyID (on right)
- Map Product -> ID (on left) to ProductID (on right)

But, it doesn't work.  It gives this error:
Error 3025: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 175:Must specify mapping for all key properties (Company_Product.SKU) of table Company_Product.

So that particular association is invalid, because it uses Company_Product as the table, but doesn't map the SKU field to anything.

Also, while I was researching this, I came across this "Best Practice" tidbit from the book Entity Framework 4.0 Recipies (note that for an association table with extra fields, besides to 2 FKs, they refer to the extra fields as the "payload".  In your case, SKU is the payload in Company_Product).

> **Best Practice**
>
> Unfortunately, a project
>   that starts out with several,
>   payload-free, many-to-many
>   relationships often ends up with
>   several, payload-rich, many-to-many
>   relationships. Refactoring a model,
>   especially late in the development
>   cycle, to accommodate payloads in the
>   many-to-many relationships can be
>   tedious. Not only are additional
>   entities introduced, but the queries
>   and navigation patterns through the
>   relationships change as well. Some
>   developers argue that every
>   many-to-many relationship should start
>   off with some payload, typically a
>   synthetic key, so the inevitable
>   addition of more payload has
>   significantly less impact on the
>   project.
>
> So here's the best practice.
>   If you have a payload-free,
>   many-to-many relationship and you
>   think there is some chance that it may
>   change over time to include a payload,
>   start with an extra identity column in
>   the link table. When you import the
>   tables into your model, you will get
>   two one-to-many relationships, which
>   means the code you write and the model
>   you have will be ready for any number
>   of additional payload columns that
>   come along as the project matures. The
>   cost of an additional integer identity
>   column is usually a pretty small price
>   to pay to keep the model more
>   flexible.

(From Chapter 2. Entity Data Modeling Fundamentals, 2.4. Modeling a Many-to-Many Relationship with a Payload)

Sounds like good advice.  Especially since you already have a payload (SKU).

Answer (score 2):

I would just like to add the following to Samuel's answer:

If you want to directly query from one side of a many-to-many relationship (with payload) to the other, you can use the following code (using the same example):

```
Company c = context.Companies.First();
IQueryable<Product> products = c.Company_Products.Select(cp => cp.Product);
```

The `products` variable would then be all `Product` records associated with the `Company c` record. If you would like to include the SKU for each of the products, you could use an anonymous class like so:

```
var productsWithSKU = c.Company_Products.Select(cp => new {
  ProductID = cp.Product.ID,
  Name = cp.Product.Name,
  Price = cp.Product.Price,
  SKU = cp.SKU
});
foreach (var
```

You can encapsulate the first query in a read-only property for simplicity like so:

```
public partial class Company
{
  public property IQueryable<Product> Products
  {
    get { return Company_Products.Select(cp => cp.Product); }
  }
}
```

You can't do that with the query that includes the SKU because you can't return anonymous types. You would have to have a definite class, which would typically be done by either adding a non-mapped property to the `Product` class or creating another class that inherits from `Product` that would add an SKU property. If you use an inherited class though, you will not be able to make changes to it and have it managed by EF - it would only be useful for display purposes.

Cheers. :)