# Entity Framework mapping of 3 tables with relationship between each other

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, relationship

Here's my problem:
I have 3 tables in my database

1. Movies (list of movies)

   - ID
   - OriginalTitle
     ...
2. Genres (table with all possible genres)

   - ID
   - Name
3. RelatedGenres (those genres that belog to a specific movie and point a specific genre, since movie can have more than 1 genre)

   - ID
   - MovieID
   - GenreID

The relationships are as folows:

Movies.ID -> RelatedGenres.MovieID -> Genres.ID

I have a model with assosiations (navigation properties).
**What I get:**

```
class Movie
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string OriginalTitle { get; set; }
   public ObjectCollection<RelatedGenre> RelatedGenres { get; set; }
}
```

where

```
class RelatedGenre
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public int MovieID { get; set; }
   public ObjectCollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

**What I want:**

```
class Movie
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string OriginalTitle { get; set; }
   public ObjectCollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, i want to skip data from this array of RelatedGenres & just get array of concrete Genres...

How can I achive this?
Thanks in advance =)

Comment: So you are wanting to combine two tables into one entity correct ? are you having trouble because its a collection ?

Comment: This question is exactly the same, and the answer works. Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework many-to-many question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168016/entity-framework-many-to-many-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove th `ID` column of the `RelatedGenres` table. The join table of many-to-many relationship should only contain the keys of the participating entities.

EF will automatically model the relationship as you have shown in the final code sample.

Comment: Just make sure you make `{MovieID, GenreID}` the primary key of the `RelatedGenres` table, or your structure will allow duplicate associations (which isn't _that_ useful in this case).